# How can I check a webpage image before displaying it?

Tags: javascript, synchronous

I need to access and display a commercial webpage which changes depending on the parameters passed. I've simplified it here as a call to: www.mywebpage.com?index=42.

With certain parameters the webpage returns an error page. I want to trap this and do something else. 
The code below works.  I set up an invisible buffer image and load the webpage to it. Then in the onload() function I draw it onto a canvas element and check some pixel colours (here simplified to checking one byte of one pixel)

If everything is OK. I load the main image.

```
 var imgMain = document.getElementById("imgDisplay");

    var imgCopy = new Image();
    callURL = "www.mywebpage.com?index=42";
    imgCopy.src = callURL;            

    imgCopy.onload = function() {
    var context = document.createElement('CANVAS').getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(imgCopy, 0, 0);.  
    var pixel1_1 = context.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data; 
    if(pixel1_1[0] == 228)  imgMain.src = callURL;

    };
```

This code only works within the onload() function. Despite the fact that everybody tells me that JavaScript is a synchronous language it's not possible to set imgCopy and check it before going on.

Mainly for readability purposes I would like to be able to delay execution until imgCopy is fully loaded, then call a Boolean function to perform the tests on the image.

Does anybody have any ideas?
Many thanks
Tony Reynolds (UK)

---

As I didn't get a response I decided not to be so lazy and did some work with Promises. Eventually I came up with:

```
 const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    img.src = callURL;
    resolve('Success!');
});

promise.then(function(value) {
  var context;
  context = document.createElement('CANVAS').getContext('2d');
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0); 
  var pixel1_1 = context.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;
};
```

So loading the image is embedded within a Promise,  and the .then function I hoped would only execute when the Promise was resolved.  It didn't work....
Does anybody know why not?
Thanks
Tony Reynolds

Comment: Even though JS is synchronous every network request (like loading an image) runs asynchronously. The code you posted seems right to me and the only thing I don't quite get is why you need to render it into a canvas and check the pixel color. If you only care for the image being loaded and not returned a server error simply hooking up onto the onload event should be enough.

Comment: The code works fine. It's just that for readability I would prefer to do something like, 1. Load the image into a buffer. 2. Check it. 3. Do one action or another.  Every other language I know works like that. I thought that maybe issuing a Promise and waiting for the result might work, but I'm not familiar with Promises.

Comment: Set the onload before you set the image url

Answer (score 0):

Is your code actually working or did you mis-copy, because the line `imgCopy = callURL;` makes no sense. It should be `imgCopy.src = callURL;`. And as Griffin says, set `onload` before setting `src`.

Comment: Apologies. It should indeed be imgCopy.src (now edited).  My question still stands however.  Promises are supposed to be a way around 'callback hell' but they don't seem to be well understood.